# Call function within autocomplete jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm working with the `autocomplete` jQuery plugin, but I have faced two main problems.

1. Calling a function within the `autocomplete` function
2. Getting the value of `textbox` to pass with function

**Html**

```
<input id="txtDemo" type="text" />
```

**Js**

```
$("#txtDemo").autocomplete({
   source: availableTags
});
```

This is my **function**, Value is value of `textbox`

```
function Demo (value)
{
//code for getting value from code behind in the form of array
}
```

Comment: Where do you call this function ?

Comment: within autocomplete function

Comment: what do you mean by within autocomplete function

Comment: my main objective is fetch data in autocomplete plugin from database but i don't know how we call another function after call autocomplete function source

Comment: @ArunPJohny I think Op don't want to handle it externally instead searching for a built in autocomplete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an event handler like this

```
$('#txtDemo').on('change', function(){
 var value = $(this).val();
 Demo (value); //pass the value as paramter
});

//Handle it here
function Demo (value) {
 //code for getting value from code behind in the form of array
}
```

---

**From your comments:**  Possible using `select`

> [**select( event, ui )Type:**](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select) autocompleteselect
>
> Triggered when an item is selected from the menu. The default action
>   is to replace the text field's value with the value of the selected
>   item.

```
$("#txtDemo").autocomplete({   
   source: availableTags,
   select: function( event, ui ) {
            demo(ui.item.value);          
      }

});
```

Here is sample [**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/EBduF/473/)

Hope you can understand.

Comment: sorry but i want to call function within autocomplete function

Comment: A callback object, for more information check out http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select

Comment: your fiddle is very nice.. you are very close to my answer. i want call function in source

Comment: May I know the reason?  Also I think it is not possible.

Comment: because i want set source data which is fetch from code behind..

Comment: thank you help me to much. i done it..

Comment: can you also suggest me how me apply height on it and scroll bar appear when item is to much to it

Comment: @Subhash you're getting scroll?  maybe css conflict could have occured.  Anyway take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282320/jquery-ui-autocomplete-1-8-scroll.  will help you.

Comment: add five more item to your list and apply them fix height upto five item show at a time and then scroll bar apply

Comment: @Subhash Oh you need a scroll.  I misunderstood as you want to remove the scroll.  here I have a new fiddle with fixed height http://jsfiddle.net/EBduF/475/

Comment: `.ui-autocomplete { max-height: 100px;overflow-y: scroll; }` is the hack.