# JQuery autocomplete on selection run function

Tags: jquery

I have this code in jquery:

```
var data = <?php echo $data; ?>;
    $("#contact_email").autocomplete({
        source:data,
        select: function(e, ui) {
            e.preventDefault()
            $(this).val(ui.item.label);
            $("#contact_email_sequence").val(ui.item.value);

            GetCustomerDetails();
        }
    });
```

the autocomplete is working fine, however its not running my `GetCustomerDetails` function on select.

when i select an option from the autocomplete list the list does not dissapear however the option is selected into the input field

Comment: What is inside `GetCustomerDetails`

Comment: currently, just an alert("test");

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call function within autocomplete jQuery plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510926/call-function-within-autocomplete-jquery-plugin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the following code:

```
var data = <?php echo $data; ?>;
    $("#contact_email").autocomplete({
        source:data,
        select: function(e, ui) {
            $("#contact_email").val(ui.item.label);
            $("#contact_email_sequence").val(ui.item.value);
            GetCustomerDetails();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please try the above

Answer (score 0):

Hi find fiddle URL for demo:

```
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
    source: function( req, resp ) {
        $.post( "/echo/json/", {
            json: '["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]',
            delay: 1
        }, function(data) {
            resp( data );
        }, "JSON" );
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
            demo(ui.item.value);          
      }
});
function demo(value) {
alert(value);

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EBduF/473/